# How can I run `gcloud preview app setup-managed-vms` without this error?

Tags: google-app-engine, docker, google-compute-engine, boot2docker, gcloud

When I run 
`gcloud --verbosity debug preview app setup-managed-vms`
I get the following error I don't know how to fix
`google.appengine.tools.docker.containers.ImageError: Image with tag localhost:49153/google/appengine-java was not found`

I posted [the whole verbose stacktrace on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/LJxBDsHq).

I am running Google Cloud SDK 0.9.40 and docker 1.3.2.

I had a different problem with the 0.9.39, uninstalled and reinstalled everything, but v0.9.40 still doesn't seem to do it.

How can I get past this?

Comment: This is exactly what I have observed: https://gist.github.com/xuru/604da3c02ec96904d352#comment-1356364

Comment: I am also blogging about my setup so far: http://tuxdna.in/blog/2014/12/14/google-app-engine-with-managedvms-and-boot2docker-so-far/

Comment: Yeah it seems a wide spread issue. Hope they're gonna fix it soon.

Comment: @tuxdna I'm curious... Have you enabled the compute engine billing in your google account? I have not, not to waste the free trial money. I would like to test my app locally first, and billind shouldn't be a problem there, but I'm not sure now...

Comment: yes I have billing enabled.

Comment: From the errors in your pastebin, with all the HTTPS failures and connection reset by peer, it seems as though you might be experiencing the same issue as the person documented [here](http://viget.com/extend/how-to-use-docker-on-os-x-the-missing-guide). Are you on OS X?

Comment: @anonymous4444 I executed what's on the first step on that article a couple of times. You were referring to that, no?

Comment: That's fine - you should have executed that regardless. You only need to execute it once. It's "Install VirtualBox". Now, can you please tell me: Are you on OS X?

Comment: @anonymous4444 Yes I am. Why?

Comment: I used Ubuntu 14.10 for those steps. Even if I was on OS X, would it make any different ? I am using VirtuaBox for the Boot2Docker VM.